# Plotting a function outside its defined interval

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a function, $f(t)$ which is $f(t)=t-t^2$ **IF** $t\in [0,1]$. The function is *odd*, **and has a period of 2.**   I want to draw it on the interval $[-2,2]$. How is that done, since it is only defined on $[0,1]$, except for ignoring the boundaries and drawing $f(t)$ on an undefined interval?

Thanks

Comment: The makes makes no sense. If the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$, you cannot draw it on the interval $[-2,2]$. At most, you can *extend* $f$ to an odd function on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Note the change Jose. I forgot to add the period!

Comment: Then you want to *extend* $f$ to $[-2,2]$ rather than just to *draw* there. Am I right?

Comment: Just to draw it there, not extend really.

Comment: Then the question still makes no sense.

Comment: Interesting. I will inform the Prof.

Comment: Hi José, I updated the question with a correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have a function $f(t)=t−t^2$ which is defined on $t\in[0,1]$. The function is odd, ..."

This makes no sense. For a function to be odd it needs to be defined in a set that is symmetric w.r.t $0$

A function $f(t)=t−t^2$ which is defined on $[0,1]$ may be **extended** in a unique way to an odd function defined on $[-1,1]$, and it can be extended in an infinity of ways to a odd function defined on $[-2,2]$

By the way, the unique odd function that extends $f$ to $[-1,1]$ is $g(t) = t - \left|t\right| t$

Edit: After the edition the question makes more sense. There's a unique odd function with period $2$ that takes the value $t-t^2$ for $t \in [0,1]$. That function is $$\left(t-2\left\lfloor\frac{t+1}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\left(1-\left|t-2\left\lfloor\frac{t+1}{2}\right\rfloor\right|\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. Can you check the update in the question and see how it affects this?